# yum security updates list not longer updating

Tags: centos, yum

I have a server that no longer lists the current security relevant updates when using:

```
yum list-security or yum --security check-updates
```

At one point yum tried to update a package and couldn't figure out how to resolve the dependencies. Since that time, new security updates aren't showing (I know there are some because I run other server with similar software packages). Yum shows that the only security relevant package is the one that failed. What steps can I take to get yum working again?

`yum update` still works on any package I manually tell it to update.

Comment: Have you run yum clean all and run yum update?

Comment: @Chida - I'll try that. It sounds like a good idea

Comment: @Chida - Thanks, that did it. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick,

```
    # yum clean all
    # yum update
```